# How to use event and listener in laravel to pass the message

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to get the message in events and listeners when the event is fire but I am not getting the message .

My controller code

```
public function usermeta()
{
    $message = 'message';
    $res = Event::fire(new webhooks($message));
    dd($res);
}
```

My event code

```
class webhooks extends Event
{
use SerializesModels;

public $message;
public function __construct($message)
{
    //
    $this->$message = $message;
 }


public function broadcastOn()
{
    return [];
}
}
```

listeners

```
class webhookslistener implements ShouldQueue
{

protected $message;
public function __construct()
{
}

public function handle(webhooks $event)
{
    Storage::put('Subscription.log', $event->message);
    dd($event->message); //I want the message here
}
}
```

Comment: In the construct it should be `$this->message = $message;`

Comment: @KinshukLahiri I am adding this but I give the error
`Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $message ]] in class App\Listeners\webhookslistener`

Comment: What is the output of `$res`?

Comment: @KinshukLahiri nothing it give the above error.

Comment: You need to initialize the webhooks class in the webhookslistner class first